# Angular ng-if="" with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am trying to get started on angular development. And after reviewing the documentation some questions persist. How do i best write a `ng-if` with multiple arguments corresponding to

`if( a && b)` or `if( a || b )`

Answer (score 181, accepted):

It is possible.

```
<span ng-if="checked && checked2">
  I'm removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
</span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UKNoaaJX5KG3J7AswhLV?p=preview

Answer (score 18):

Just to clarify, be aware bracket placement is important!

These can be added to any HTML tags... span, div, table, p, tr, td etc.

**AngularJS**

```
ng-if="check1 && !check2" -- AND NOT
ng-if="check1 || check2" -- OR
ng-if="(check1 || check2) && check3" -- AND/OR - Make sure to use brackets
```

**Angular2**+

```
*ngIf="check1 && !check2" -- AND NOT
*ngIf="check1 || check2" -- OR
*ngIf="(check1 || check2) && check3" -- AND/OR - Make sure to use brackets
```

It's best practice not to do calculations directly within ngIfs, so assign the variables within your component, and do any logic there.

```
boolean check1 = Your conditional check here...
...
```

Answer (score 9):

For people looking to do if statements with multiple 'or' values.

```
<div ng-if="::(a || b || c || d || e || f)"><div>
```

Comment: what are the two dots in front? Shouldn't it work without them and the brackets? Based on javaCity's example, this doesn't even work http://plnkr.co/edit/qdIysgbxtEUVB2WMJa1i?p=preview

Comment: the dots are Angular's syntax for one-time (as opposed to two-way) binding

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.
for example checkout:

```
<div class="singleMatch" ng-if="match.date | date:'ddMMyyyy' === main.date &&  match.team1.code === main.team1code && match.team2.code === main.team2code">
    //Do something here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using a function in controller scope.

##### Controller

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.ControllerModel = {
        check1: true,
        check2: false,
    };

    $scope.Validate_ItemOfMyList(item) {

        if (item == null) item = $scope.ControllerModel;

        return item.check1 && !item.check2;

    };

}]);
```

##### View

```html
<p ng-if="Validate_ItemOfMyList()" >This item is valid!</p>
```

##### Using ng-repeate

```html
<div class="myClass"
    ng-repeat="item in MyList"
>
    <p ng-if="Validate_ItemOfMyList(item)">This item is valid!</p>
</div>
```